# Python3 failing to `az login`

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, subprocess, azure-cli

> **What specific changes need to be made to the syntax below
> in order for the Python3 function below to report that the
> `az login` cli command has succeeded, or to report
> useful error message if it has not?**

**CURRENT FUNCTION:**

Here is the function we are currently using to try to `az login` from a Python program:

```
def runShellCommand(commandToRun):
  proc = subprocess.Popen( commandToRun,cwd=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
  while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    print("line is: ", line)
    if line:
      thetext=line.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\r|\n')
      decodedline=ansi_escape.sub('', thetext)
      print(decodedline)
    else:
      break
```

**CURRENT CALL TO THE ABOVE FUNCTION:**

Here is the code that we are currently using to call the above function on a Windows 10 computer:

```
azdoLoginCmd= "ECHO " + azPat + " | " + "az devops login --organization "+organization 
print("azdoLoginCmd is: ", azdoLoginCmd)
runShellCommand(azdoLoginCmd)
quit("!BREAKPOINT!")
```

Note the shell command inside the `azdoLoginCmd` variable must run on Windows.

**CURRENT OUTPUT:**

Here is the output that gets printed in the Windows CMD when we run the above code:

```
azdoLoginCmd is:  ECHO pat-value-redacted-for-security | az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/OurOrgName
line is:  b''
!BREAKPOINT!
```

As you can see, zero output is being returned from the `runShellCommand(...)` function even though we validated the PAT value and the Organization URL.

> **What specific changes must be made to the above in order to provide meaningful return values so the Python3 program can determine whether or not the `az login` succeeded?**

Comment: When you successfully log into az devops, there is no output. Try your code with incorrect credentials and see if you get an error. I tested your code with a bad PAT and it gave me the failed login message.

Answer (score 0):

@Nick is right in that the `az devops login` command does not produce any output in case of a successful login. You can instead check for the invalid login case as you'd see an error message like the following if the provided credentials are incorrect:

```
Failed to authenticate using the supplied token.
```

Also note that, if you have already signed in with `az login` interactively or if you're using a user name and password, you're not required to provide a token because the `az devops` commands now support sign-in through `az login`. However, you can't sign in as the service principal via `az login`. In that scenario, a PAT is required. For other sign-in options, check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows) article.

Comment: `az login --verbose` does not display anything for me...:s

Comment: @ntg You should see a log like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67Y9x.png). If this doesn't work, try `az login --use-device-code`.